# Qwt Realtime Dial

Tags: multithreading, qt, plot, real-time, qwt

I want to create a simple Qwt widget that only contains a dial. The value displayed on the dial (i.e. the position of the dial) should be updated according to some input data which I collect from a separate thread.

I can generate my dial within a main window class, and I can create and start my data capture on a separate thread within the main window class, like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    // create the dial
    QDial* pDial = new QDial;

    // create the data class to capture data from an external source
    DataClass* pData = new DataClass;

    // start the data class thread
    pData->Start();

    // I can get the latest value of data at any instant like this:
    int x = pData->GetData();

    // I need to connect the data value to the dial, so that the
    // dial always displays the value of the data capture device.

}
```

What can I insert so that GetData() is constantly called to update the value displayed on the dial?

Answer (score 1):

I worked out an answer - no idea if it's the best way of doing it.

Just pass a pointer to the dial into the constructor of the DataClass:

```
DataClass* pData = new DataClass(pDial);
```

And within the DataClass class, include a QDial* member and SetDialValue method:

```
class DataClass
{
public:
    Position(QDial* pDial);
    .
    .
    .
    void SetValue(int x);

private:

    QDial* _pDial;
    int _val;
}
```

Set _pDial to the pointer passed in the constructor, and then whenever new data is received, update the dial via the SetValue method:

```
void DataClass::SetValue(int x)
{
    _pDial->setValue(x);

    return;
}
```

I've left out mutex locks etc for the pDial pointer, but those are of course necessary.

Comment: ***I've left out mutex locks etc for the pDial pointer, but those are of course necessary.*** I would avoid a mutex using signals and slots.

Comment: How come? Don't I want to protect shared variables while I write to them on a separate thread?

Comment: With signals and slots you eliminate the variables that are shared across threads. In this case you would make `DataClass::SetValue(int x)` a slot. And the class that updates the value would emit a signal (connected to this `SetValue(int))` that sets the value. Qt would detect that there are more than 1 threads involved and post the signal using a queued connection.